# Assign callback URL to the sms number via Nexmo API

Tags: java, php, .net, sms, vonage

I want to assign callback URL via Nexmo API.

I'm saying about this URL:
[image: Nexmo stttings]

I just buy the new SMS number via Nexmo API: [Nexmo API docs: 'Buy number'](https://docs.nexmo.com/index.php/developer-api/number-buy).
I'm using .NET for this, but the language doesn't matter.

```
var client = new WebClient();
client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

string ApiBuyUrl = "http://rest.nexmo.com/number/buy";
string ApiBuyParams = "api_key={0}&api_secret={1}&country={2}&msisdn={3}";
// params assignment
string buyResultString = client.UploadString(ApiBuyUrl, apiBuyParams);
```

Then I want to assign to this just bought number the Callback URL.

I read the documentation, but didn't find anything about it. Is it possible to implement in the runtime?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the HTTP request to update the Callback URL of the specified phone number.

> POST
>   /number/update?api_key={api_key}&api_secret={api_secret}&country={country}&msisdn={msisdn}&moHttpUrl={url}&moSmppSysType={sysType}&voiceCallbackType={type}&voiceCallbackValue={value}&voiceStatusCallback={status}

[Here](https://docs.nexmo.com/index.php/developer-api/number-update) you will find more information.